# is there a way to scrollToOffset with Animated.Flatlist?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I need to be able to scroll **animated.flatlist** component to certain offset on **componentDidUpdate**, but somehow scrollToOffset only available for **flatlist** and  not **animated.flatlist**, and I have to use this **animated.flatlist** component for some reason, is there a way? have try **scrollTo** and **scrollToOffset** both return error.